# role of script manager in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

what script manager exactly do in the asp.net page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ScriptManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx) - Manages ASP.NET Ajax script libraries and script files, partial-page rendering, and client proxy class generation for Web and application services.

Answer (score 2):

"Manages ASP.NET Ajax script libraries and script files, partial-page rendering, and client proxy class generation for Web and application services." - MSDN

Also you can check this [MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163354.aspx) for a good reading.